# How to upload a file to a hub site in SharePoint Online using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I've created a new app, generated app id and secret, assigned full permissions for https://mydomain.sharepoint.com but I can't upload a file to the Shared Documents folder using the following PowerShell commands:

```
$SharePointURL = "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com"
$SharePointDestPath = "/Shared Documents"
$file = "some-file"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SharePointURL -ClientId "asddsf-9999-4a88-8c79-ab8cabc67889" -ClientSecret "123343sdsfsdgfg2343434345656=" -WarningAction Ignore
Write-Host "done"
Write-Host "Uploading output file ... " -NoNewline
Add-PnPFile -Path $file -Folder $SharePointDestPath
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

I am getting 'access denied':

```
PS E:\sharepoint_online> .\script.ps1
Connecting to SharePoint online ... done
Uploading output file ... Add-PnPFile : Access denied.
At E:\sharepoint_online\script.ps1:26 char:1
+ Add-PnPFile -Path $file -Folder $SharePointDestPath -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPFile], ServerUnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.AddFile
```

I'm probably doing something wrong or didn't make the proper settings. Can you please help me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you connect fine, but not allowed to upload. It seems like permission issues on your app creation.  Please verify by going to https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx (if you want to upload to main site, normally you would want to upload to sub sites, but just using your example)
On that page type the “Client ID” that you got when you created the app into the “App ID” field and then click the “Lookup” button
Add the following into  Permission Request XML:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Then click create at the bottom right hand side of the page.  On the next page click "Trust It" to set permissions and try again.

Comment: Please fix grammar (especially punctuation) and substitute the image with a code block.